# Specs2 GWT multiple scenarios

Tags: scala, specs2

I try to play around with Specs2 GWT ( http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.structure.GivenWhenThenPage.html), but I wonder how to write multiple test scenarios, I cant find documents related to that.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy, you only have to add the second scenario to your test (after ending the first).

There exists an [example](https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/blob/master/examples/src/test/scala/examples/GWTSpec.scala) on the github page containing two scenarios.